# How do I only disable a section in a certain InstType, but force it on otherwise (even in the "Custom" InstType)?

Tags: nsis

I have a `Section` that is set to `RO` and occurs in all `InstType`s except for a special one.

When the user first selects the special `InstType` and then selects "Custom" as the `InstType` the section is unchecked and can't be checked again in the "Custom" `InstType`.

So everything is fine except that when the users selects the "Custom" `InstType` the `Section` should always be checked again.

Only in the special `InstType` use case it should be unchecked.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enforce whatever logic you want in .onSelChange:

```
!include WinMessages.nsh
!include LogicLib.nsh
!include Sections.nsh

Page Components
Page InstFiles

InstType "Normal1"
!define CIT_Special 1
InstType "Special"
InstType "Normal2"

Section Foo
SectionIn 1 2 3
SectionEnd

Section Bar SEC_Special
SectionIn 1 3
SectionIn RO
SectionEnd

Section Baz
SectionIn 1 2 ;3 << Not the same as Foo just to have some sort of difference
SectionEnd

Function .onSelChange
;Normally you would call GetCurInstType here, but it seems we need a little hack to detect the custom section
FindWindow $1 "#32770" "" $HWNDPARENT
GetDlgItem $1 $1 0x3F9
SendMessage $1 ${CB_GETCURSEL} 0 0 $2
SendMessage $1 ${CB_GETITEMDATA} $2 0 $2
${If} $2 = ${CIT_Special}
    !insertmacro UnselectSection ${SEC_Special}
${Else}
    !insertmacro SelectSection ${SEC_Special}
${EndIf}
FunctionEnd
```

Comment: Turns out the GetCurInstType behavior is by design, it returns the current insttype which is not necessarily the same as the combobox selection.